# How to round of bar values in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I want to show the rounded up values in the graph.

I don't want to use the tool tip solution since I have disabled it.

```
var chartyaxis = {
    min: 0,
    title: {
        text: 'Scores'
    },
    stackLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        style: {
            fontWeight: 'normal',
            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'white',
        }
    }
}
```

If the cumulative value of my chart is 45.9 I need to round it up to 50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `formatter` option : [stackLabels formatter](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.stackLabels.formatter)
And use the javascript Math object to round the values :

```
stackLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    style: {
        fontWeight: 'normal',
        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'white',
    },
    formatter: function(){
        return Math.ceil(this.total);
    }
}
```